# Error in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I am developing an android application.

```
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    weightSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    weightUnitSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    heightSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
```

Here I am getting error in these line i.e R cannot be resolved to a variable
can any solve this.

Comment: clean the project and build the project.

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R is a generated class. You can find R.java in /gen folder if it is generated.

If there is no R.java in /gen, your project may have some other errors that you first fix them.
First fix any other error and then clean build your project.If that doesn't help, delete /gen folder, and clean build again.

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure that none of your XML files have any errors in them
2. Run Project -> Clean...
3. Make sure your java file is in the same package given in the Manifest. If not, import the R file manually.

Answer (score 0):

Check the packages you have imported. If you see Android.R then delete it and clean.